# Online font CSP header not working in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, fonts, content-security-policy

I am using 3 online fonts url in my chrome extension given below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/axiforma" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
```

in my manifest.json file I define the header in 3 ways like below both with font-src and style-src

```
"content_security_policy": "font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com/ 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/ 'self' https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"

"content_security_policy": "font-src https://themes.googleusercontent.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Also added style-src with font-src but still it is showing violation error.

[image]
[image]

Need help what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> in my manifest.json file I define the header **in 3 ways** like below both
> with font-src and style-src
>
> `"content_security_policy": "font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com/ 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com/ 'self' https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"`
>
> `"content_security_policy": "font-src https://themes.googleusercontent.com/ https://fonts.gstatic.com/ https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"`

You did shown only 2 CSPs from 3. Let me guess, the **third** has `font-src` related list:
  `font-src https://themes.googleusercontent.com/;`
because it is it that is contained in the error messages.

You need to define only ONE CSP, in case of multiple CSP they  combines with logical "AND" - are allowed the sources that meet all CSPs simultaneously (sources should pass unscrathed through all CSPs).

Therefore your CSP should be:

```
style-src 'self' https://fonts.cdnfonts.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com;

font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.cdnfonts.com;

object-src 'self';

script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com;
```

`*`all host-sources from `<link rel="stylesheet"` should be in `style-src` directive  because those are a styles.

`**` trailing slash **/** can be omitted.

`**` in the `font-src` it need to specify host-names from `src:` in [CSS constructs](https://csplite.com/csp/test189/) kind of:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Reenie Beanie';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Reenie Beanie'), local('ReenieBeanie'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s.roboto/v20/KFOlCnqE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: Added this 
 "content_security_policy": "style-src 'self' https://fonts.cdnfonts.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com https://fonts.cdnfonts.com https://themes.googleusercontent.com; script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com;  object-src 'self'"
 Still same

Comment: You can remove all `https://` from CSP rules: `font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com fonts.cdnfonts.com;`, `style-src 'self' fonts.cdnfonts.com fonts.googleapis.com fonts.googleapis.com;`.

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: It is happening in only one site, does it involve website restriction or something?

Comment: Yes,it can be if you inject fonts into web page which publish its own CSP. Check the meta tag and CSP header of this "problematic" site.

Comment: I solved it my downloading the font file and use it locally.